# Simple or perfect

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

Recently I wrote this sentence: I am sending you the edited mail as I typed the wrong data before. At first I was happy with it, but since then I ve been doubting the use of past simple in the second part of a sentence. Isn't past perfect a better choice instead of simple?

Answer (score 1):

Your email was better in the past simple. To use the past perfect you would have had to define the moment in time before which you had typed the wrong data - this was not a part of your message.

Instead of 'I typed the wrong data before' it would be clearer to say 'I typed the wrong data in the last one'